# Why are the pulmonary vein and artery not like the rest of circulatory system?

Tags: human-anatomy, blood-circulation

I'm learning anatomy. What I learnt is that we have arteries that have oxygenated blood which appears red in color, and branch blood to arterioles to deliver blood to cells via capillaries from where de-oxygeneated blood is collected via venules into veins to go back for oxygenation. So:

> artery = oxygenated
>
> vein = de-oxygenated

However, in defining the pulmonary vein and pulmonary artery, I see the reverse of these definitions.

The pulmonary artery is for de-oxygenated blood.

Why is it so?

Comment: Ask youself, what function is served by pulmonary circulation? What function is served by systemic circulation? What part of the anatomy connects the two?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is true that nearly all arteries carry oxygenated blood and nearly all veins carry de-oxygenated blood, but that is not what defines them. [Arteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artery) are blood vessels that carry blood *away* from the heart, and [veins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vein) carry blood *towards* the heart. If you look at the situation in that light, the naming makes sense: the pulmonary artery is carrying de-oxygenated blood *away* from the heart to the lungs, and the pulmonary vein is carrying the *re*-oxygenated blood back to the heart, to be pumped through the rest of the body.

Comment: Although [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_venous_system) complicate classification.